# Azure blob storage download to stream returning "" asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am currently trying to download a file from Azure blob storage using the DownloadToStream method to download the contents of a blob as a text string.
However I am not getting anything back but an empty string.

Here is my code that I use to connect to the azure blob container and retrieve the blob file.

```
    public static string DownLoadFroalaImageAsString(string blobStorageName, string companyID)
    {
        // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(companyID.ToLower());

        //retrieving the actual filename of the blob
        string removeString = "BLOB/";
        string trimmedString = blobStorageName.Remove(blobStorageName.IndexOf(removeString), removeString.Length);

        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "trimmedString"
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob2 = container.GetBlockBlobReference(trimmedString);

        string text;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            blockBlob2.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
            text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
        return text;
    }
```

I was following along [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs) documentation however I cannot seem to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> However I am not getting anything back but an empty string.

I test your supplied code on my side, it works correctly. I assume that the **test blob content is empty** in your case. We could trouble shooting with following ways:

1.please have a try to check the Length of memoryStream. If length equal 0 we could know that the blob content is empty.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    blockBlob2.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
    var length = memoryStream.Length;
    text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
 }
```

2.We could upload a blob with content to container, we could do that with Azure portal or  [Microsoft Azure storage explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) easily. And please have a try test it with uploaded blob.

Comment: Thanks! I have a problem with how I am uploading files to the blob storage container, hence why my code doesn't return anything as the file does not exist. :-S

Comment: @HaydenPassmore As far as the issue with uploading goes: is the position in the sourcestream (re)set to 0? Got me quite a few times.

Comment: @RickvandenBosch I was having an issue with my stream position thanks. I posted a question earlier today [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46418526/uploading-file-to-azure-blob-storage-then-sending-http-response-with-the-files-b]

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the text from the blob, you can use DownloadTextAsync()

```
var text = await blockBlob2.DownloadTextAsync();
```

If you want to return file stream back to an API respoinse, you can use FileStreamResult which is IActionResult.

```
var stream = await blockBlob2.OpenReadAsync();
return File(stream, blockBlob2.Properties.ContentType, "name");
```